# JSON Structure for List of Objects

Tags: java, json, jaxb

I would like to know, whats the right structure for a list of objects in JSON.

We are using JAXB to convert the POJO's to JSON.

Here is the choices, Please direct me what is right.

```
foos: [
             foo:{..},
             foo:{..}
      ]
```

or

```
   foos : [
           {...},
           {...}
          ]
```

If the first structure is right, what is the JAXB annotation I should use to get the structure right.

Comment: "using JAXB to convert the POJO's to JSON".... how?

Answer (score 56, accepted):

The first example from your question,

> ```js
> foos: [
>     foo: { ... },
>     foo: { ... }
> ]
> ```

is in invalid syntax. You cannot have object properties inside a plain array.

The second example from your question,

> ```js
> foos: [
>     { ... },
>     { ... }
> ]
> ```

is right although it is not *strict* JSON. It's a *relaxed* form of JSON wherein quotes in string keys are omitted.

Following is the correct one when you want to obey *strict* JSON:

```js
"foos": [
    { ... },
    { ... }
]
```

[This "Mastering JSON" tutorial by Patrick Hunlock](http://web.archive.org/web/20180919022127/http://index-of.es/JS/Mastering_JSON_(JavaScript_Object_Notation).pdf), may help to learn about JSON and [this site](https://www.jsonlint.com/) may help to validate JSON.

Answer (score 119):

The second is almost correct:

```
{
    "foos" : [{
        "prop1":"value1",
        "prop2":"value2"
    }, {
        "prop1":"value3", 
        "prop2":"value4"
    }]
}
```

Comment: This doesnt validate on jsonlint :(
I am tempted to think jsonlint is wrong though :-|

Comment: @RamanpreetSingh - If you're validating via `jsonlint`, then you'll need to also add quotes around `foos` at the top level.

Comment: I added quotes and curly braces at the top level and it works. Thanks!

Answer (score 30):

As others mentioned, Justin's answer was close, but not quite right.  I tested this using Visual Studio's "Paste JSON as C# Classes"

```
{
    "foos" : [
        {
            "prop1":"value1",
            "prop2":"value2"
        },
        {
            "prop1":"value3", 
            "prop2":"value4"
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. I use jsonformatter page to test the json validator.
2. try to use jsonwhatever

example:

```
list_a = func_generator_of_objects()

json_string = jsonwhatever('foos',list_a)
```